# Spring properties editor error upon upgrading to Eclipse 2022 ("Failed to create the part's controls", NCDF error "javax/inject/Provider")

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My version of Eclipse was updated to 2022-03 this morning, and now I cannot open the application.properties file in my Spring projects.  (At least, not in the Spring editor; it's still fine in a plain text editor, of course.)

The error message is "Failed to create the part's controls"

Stack trace begins
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/inject/Provider"

Nested error
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider cannot be found by org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.properties.editor_3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE"

Session data from the error:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.23.0.I20220308-0310
java.version=15.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxx/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxx/.eclipse_keyring
```

I've tried running from the CL with the "-clean" flag.  I've also tried renaming directories having to do with editing in my .plugins folder, to have them regenerated anew.  No luck.  I did check for later updates in case a known bug went out in the distribution last night.

If it matters, I have a Java8 JRE on my machine, a Mac.  Anyone else having this problem, and any ideas on what to try next?  Thanks.

Comment: `20201213` in `org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.properties.editor_3.9.15.202012132325-RELEASE` means that it is from December 13, 2020. Probably your old (and outdated?) Spring editor does not work with the current Eclipse 2022-03.

Comment: More likely it's not compatible with Java 11 or newer--which has been a requirement since Eclipse 2020-09.

Answer (score 0):

i installed Spring Tools 4 (4.14.0 RELEASE) and i don't have this error anymore , like howgler said it's a problem of outdated spring editor version .

Update notes : https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/16/spring-tools-4-14-0-released